# validating Receipt in in-App-Purchase?

Tags: iphone

what is purpose of the following in in-App-purchase
1)validating Receipt
2)purchase
3)product request
must I do all three process in my in-app-purchase application?
any example in different way (without apple explanation)?

Comment: @ScottFisher You have had previous posts edited/deleted for improperly advertising your project. I am flagging this and informing the mods that you are continuing to try to advertise here, and apparently have your 'friends' up-voting you again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Validate receipt. This is where you validate the purchase is correct and not spoofed by a user. This is best to be done on a secure server somewhere.
2. Purchase. This is the process where the user buys your product. You have to call StoreKit.
3. Request products. This is where you get product info from the App Store, so you get the correct price etc.

Yes. You must do all these 3. The code examples provided by Apple should work for these, expect validate receipt.

Try this [http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-–-in-app-purchases/](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/). Not sure if it works or not, I found it with google.